# How to programmatically change the click event from a html element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I will try to explain my problem followed by an example:

I'm wondering to switch `li` position and make them behave like the `li` that was already there:

Here's the sample:

I would like to **click** in the **left column** `li` change the place and then behave just like any other `li` from **right column**....

If you try to click back the `li` won't go back to the left column.

please help

```js
$('ul.my-list-left li').on('click',function () {
     var  total =  $('ul.my-list-right li').length;
     
     $('ul.my-list-right li').eq(total-1).after($('ul.my-list-left li').eq( $(this).index())) 
     if(total ===0){
         $('ul.my-list-right').append($('ul.my-list-left li').eq($(this).index())) 
     }
 });

 $('ul.my-list-right li').on('click',function () {
     var  total =  $('ul.my-list-left li').length; 
     
     $('ul.my-list-left li').eq(total-1).after($('ul.my-list-right li').eq( $(this).index())) 
     if(total ===0){
         $('ul.my-list-left').append($('ul.my-list-right li').eq($(this).index())) 
     }
 });
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-6">
            <div class="well">
                <ul class="my-list my-list-left">
                    <li data-value="1">Left Item 1</li>
                    <li data-value="2">Left Item 2</li>
                    <li data-value="3">Left Item 3</li>
                    <li data-value="4">Left Item 4</li>
                    <li data-value="5">Left Item 5</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-6">
            <div class="well">
                <ul class="my-list my-list-right">
                    <li data-value="1">Right Item 1</li>
                    <li data-value="2">Right Item 2</li>
                    <li data-value="3">Right Item 3</li>
                    <li data-value="4">Right Item 4</li>
                    <li data-value="5">Right Item 5</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delegate the events so that newly appended elements get the event bound when they are moved from column to column:

```
$('ul.my-list-left').on('click', 'li', function () {
     var  total =  $('ul.my-list-right li').length;

     $('ul.my-list-right li').eq(total-1).after($('ul.my-list-left li').eq( $(this).index())) 
     if(total ===0){
         $('ul.my-list-right').append($('ul.my-list-left li').eq($(this).index())) 
     }
 });

 $('ul.my-list-right').on('click', 'li', function () {
     var  total =  $('ul.my-list-left li').length; 

     $('ul.my-list-left li').eq(total-1).after($('ul.my-list-right li').eq( $(this).index())) 
     if(total ===0){
         $('ul.my-list-left').append($('ul.my-list-right li').eq($(this).index())) 
     }
 });
```

Comment: Good answer! For the OP, more about event delegation: http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate

Answer (score 2):

use `$(document).on()` to also take into account newly bounded DOM elements

`$(document).on('click', 'ul.my-list-left li' ,function () {});`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', 'ul.my-list-left li' ,function () {
        var  total =  $('ul.my-list-right li').length;

        $('ul.my-list-right li').eq(total-1).after($('ul.my-list-left li').eq( $(this).index())) 
        if(total ===0){
            $('ul.my-list-right').append($('ul.my-list-left li').eq($(this).index())) 
        }
    });

    $(document).on('click', 'ul.my-list-right li', function () {
        var  total =  $('ul.my-list-left li').length; 

        $('ul.my-list-left li').eq(total-1).after($('ul.my-list-right li').eq( $(this).index())) 
        if(total ===0){
            $('ul.my-list-left').append($('ul.my-list-right li').eq($(this).index())) 
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-6">
            <div class="well">
                <ul class="my-list my-list-left">
                    <li data-value="1">Left Item 1</li>
                    <li data-value="2">Left Item 2</li>
                    <li data-value="3">Left Item 3</li>
                    <li data-value="4">Left Item 4</li>
                    <li data-value="5">Left Item 5</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-6">
            <div class="well">
                <ul class="my-list my-list-right">
                    <li data-value="1">Right Item 1</li>
                    <li data-value="2">Right Item 2</li>
                    <li data-value="3">Right Item 3</li>
                    <li data-value="4">Right Item 4</li>
                    <li data-value="5">Right Item 5</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```